# 100 GB of Hard Drive space missing?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, trash, dolphin

[image]

Taking a look at my main hard drive, `/dev/sda6`, you can see I've used `1797GB` GB out of he `1920GB` available. The difference comes out to `122749208` bytes, or `122GB` of space left.

[image]

GParted claims I have `115.74 GB` remaining of unused storage space on that same hard drive.

[image]

Dolphin however claims I have only ~`22GB` remaining on my main hard drive. It seems to have no idea of the supposed `100GB`+ of unused storage space.

[image]

Filelight claims I have `113.3GB` remaining.

What's going on here? They are all reporting different sizes. Dolphin also believes I have < `20GB` left, when in fact I have > `100GB`.

I have a feeling it has something to with with my *Trash* folder and it's maximum size.

[image]

Originally when I clicked on trash, it seemed like the maximum size of the trash was 5-10%, which was about `100GB`. I set it down to be only `1GB` in size and still nothing has changed within Dolphin. It still reports I have ~`20GB` remaining. Why is this happening, what can I do, and how much space do I have left?

Comment: Most likely it is 5% root reserve on ext4.

Comment: 122749208 bytes are 122 MB, not 122GB.

Comment: I agree with @Pilot6. What df reports as available is the total minus used minus a part that ext4 reserves to keep the filesystems working should it become full. That reserve is by default 5%. Some other applications don't make that distinction, e.g. gparted.